# How to detect if data in the form has been changed ? MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

NOTE: I've already seen some solutions on this forum, but they don't apply in my specific case.

In my app, the user always edit the data using a modal window. When the modal first open, there is only one "Close" button visible. If the user changes any text, this button is immediately hidden and the "Cancel" and "Save" buttons become visible. The only way, that I know of, to implement this approach, is to hook up an event to all of the text controls. The quantity of text controls vary in the forms, but no more than 50. I will need to "id" and hoop up the "change" event into each one of the controls in the form. My question is, if there is a simpler way of doing it? like an event if anything in the form changes? It is OK  if the user changes the data and then changes it back and the event is fired anyway.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formPostUnitDetails", @style = "padding-right:5px" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdNo)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UnitNo)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UnitNo, new { @id="txtUnitNo")
    //..... 49 more text controls 

    <div class="panel-footer" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <input id="btnCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" value="CANCEL" style=" display: none;" />
        <input id="btnSave" type="button"   class="btn btn-success" value="SAVE CHANGES" style=" display: none;" />
        <input id="btnClose" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" value="CLOSE" />
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).on("change", "#txtUnitNo", function () { EnableButtons(); })
// 49 more text controls 

function EnableButtons() {
    $("#btnCancel").show();
    $("#btnSave").show();
    $("#btnClose").hide();
}
```

Comment: Add a class to all the elements, eg. `check-dirty`, then you only need a single selector. You may also want to hook to the `keydown` and `paste` events for better coverage.

Comment: The preferred method for the User Experience is to have buttons visible but disabled.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan : This looks like the perfect solution, but my JQuery skills are not at that level yet +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to all inputs say 'txt-input' 
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UnitNo, new { @id="txtUnitNo", @class="txt-input"})` and use class to detect change

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.txt-input', function() {
  EnableButtons();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of hooking up event handlers to each input you have, you could instead hook up an event to all inputs.

```
$('form input[type="text"]').on('change', function() {
    EnableButtons();
});
```

This works as the selector `form input[type="text"]` selects all input elements (of type text) within a form, and then binds a `change` event handler to them.

One other option is to assign all of the inputs you want to monitor a class such as `change-monitored` and then you can change your selector to `$('.change-monitored').on(...)`

---

### Demo

```js
$('.changable').on('change', function(e) {
  $('#log').append(e.target.id + ' changed to ' + $(e.target).val() + '<br/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="changable" id="input1" />
  <input type="text" class="changable" id="input2" />
  <input type="text" class="changable" id="input3" />
  <input type="text" class="changable" id="input4" />
  <input type="text" class="changable" id="input5" />
</form>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: The class idea is the best, although I'd use `js-monitor-change` (classic verb-noun), [it's good to decouple css, js and html](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: Agreed, changed to use a class. And I agree it's good to decouple them, however in the OP's case that might be overkill

Comment: @Joey Ciechanowicz Although your answer is the best, for some reason neither one of the solutions worked in my case. I will have to go with the answer below, but I will vote it up.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

fire event in all element change (input , select ,textarea , ..)

```js
  $('form').change(function () {
                console.log(this);
                alert('change');
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="name" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" value=" " />
        <select>
            <option value="value">text</option>
            <option value="value">text</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```